# Look through Spot Light

Tags: 3d-view, light

I have a spot light in my scene and I want to accurately place it. I know there was a way to do this in 2.55, but that doesn't seem to work anymore. How can I look through my light?

[image: spot lighrs]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just select the spot light, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Num-0</kbd> (zero) to turn it into an active camera (looking at -Z local axis). To keep looking through it while navigating the scene you will have to enable 'Lock Camera to View' in 'View' under the properties panel. You'll then need to press it again while selecting the camera, to set the active camera back to it.

Comment: hint - you might want to temp unlock the view from the current camera, (directly to the right of the layer buttons in the 3d view-port). then you can disable this toggle to get the original camera back.